# Is PouchDB an offline-client from CouchDB's perspective?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am currently learning about CouchDB and PouchDB. Is it correct to assume that from CouchDB's perspective PouchDB is a normal CouchDB offline-client (i.e. it follows CouchDB's proprietary replication protocols), albeit one that is implemented in JavaScript instead of Erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CouchDB's perspective there is no difference between replicating with PouchDB or replicating with another CouchDB instance. PouchDB follows the standard replication protocols, and in fact is tested against the same test suite that CouchDB uses.

Answer (score 2):

Small correction: CouchDB's protocol is by no means proprietary (see [replication.io](http://www.replication.io/) for the spec) and has several independent implementations - CouchDB, PouchDB, Couchbase Sync Gateway, Cloudant, rcouch, Couchbase Mobile, etc.

Otherwise yes, PouchDB is just another CouchDB. In fact [PouchDB Server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server) is functionally the same as CouchDB 1.6 in every way, down to the HTTP interface, the Fauxton UI, etc.